# Java: Let other threads know if GUI is ready to use

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, ready

I'm writing an application which parses `XML` files (continuously) and show the data in a GUI (`Swing`). The `ParseThread` is in the `CoreProject`, and the `GUI` is in the `GUIProject`.

The start of the `ParseThread` is connected to a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` with an ItemListener. The value of `setSelected()` is set directly after adding to the Menu. At this time the GUI does not contain the `Component` which the `ParseThread` needs to show the parsed Data.

My Solution is, that the `ParseThread` should wait until the GUI is build completely.
I thought of something like an EventQueue but I have no Idea how to code one.

Comment: Why don't you just kick off your threads after the GUI is ready?

Comment: Agree -- I'm not sure what your exact problem is, though it sounds like you could use a SwingWorker to do background processing with an added PropertyChangeListener to notify the GUI of the thread's progress.

Comment: Yes, I can't see any point in creating the thread until all the data it needs to run, (directly) exists. That said, GUI componenets should not belong in that category anyway - if the GUI is communicated with by messaging in the usual way, this problem should not occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Solution is, that the ParseThread should wait until the GUI is build completely. I thought of something like an EventQueue but I have no Idea how to code one.

you have got issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), your hard and long running task should be moved to the Background task, for Swing there are two possibilities

- (easy & simple) use `Runnable#Thread`, output to Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, including thread safe methods as are `setText`, `append` e.i.
- use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

EDIT

please to check my visulaizations for [Runnable#Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11282106/714968) this is the same thing as you connect server, parse long file e.i.,

> with invokeLater() I cannot be sure that the component exists until the call

1. create GUI,
2. show GUI,
3. some `(Swing / Util) Timer` or `user action` to invoke code that is/are redirected out of `Swing EventDispatchThread`, for this reason there are `Runnable#Thread` or `SwingWorker`
4. I'm suggest two easiest of possible ways

Comment: with invokeLater() I cannot be sure that the component exists until the call

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got my problem...
The GUI is created like this:

```
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Mainframe frame = new Mainframe();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

And at construction of the Object Mainframe this code will be executed:

```
final JCheckBoxMenuItem chckbxmntmParsing = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Parsing");
    chckbxmntmParsing.setName("mainframe.menu.data.parsing");
    localeChangedListener.add(chckbxmntmParsing);

    chckbxmntmParsing.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (chckbxmntmParsing.isSelected()) {
                parseManager.startParsing();
            } else {
                parseManager.stopParsing();
            }
        }
    });

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean enabled = false;
            String prop = PropertyManager.get().getProperty("parser.continuousparsing.enabled");
            if (prop != null) {
                if (prop.trim().equals("true") || prop.trim().equals("1")) {
                    enabled = true;
                }
            }
            chckbxmntmParsing.setSelected(enabled);
        }
    });
```

So the ParseThread will start after GUI is build.

Sorry for stealing your time

Comment: *"Sorry for stealing your time"* Speaking only for me (nobody else asks me to speak for them) but apology not accepted because you do not owe me one.  Instead, **thank you** for providing the answer to your own question!  Great for a Q&A site.  :)