# Graphics of JPanel flickering on left side

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, jcomponent

I have a java program that's should be doing something very simple. It contains a `JPanel`, on which `repaint()` is called 30 times each second. This `JPanel` overrides the `paintComponent()` method, and in this overwritten method, I take a `BufferedImage` and draw it to the JPanel.

This `BufferedImage` consists of a black image with a somewhat smaller blue rectangle inside of it. This displays, but the problem is that the left side, 50-80 pixels or so, of the screen flickers. On the leftmost part of what should be the blue rectangle, some of the pixels will sometimes appear black instead, as though there's some black overlay extending from the left side of the screen covering it, that flickers a bit each frame.

I wouldn't think just drawing a rectangle would be so consuming that it would cause graphical bugs with something like this; is it? I can't figure out why this would be happening, so do any of you have any idea what would cause a black "flicker" on the left of either a `BufferedImage` or a `Graphics2D`?

'Runnable example(please add the imports)':

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{
public int width, height;
public long lastTime;
public BufferedImage canvas;
public Panel(int a, int b){
width = a;
height = b;
canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
}
public void drawRect(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int color){
for(int i=0; i<w; i++){
for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
canvas.setRGB(i + startX, j + startY, color);
}
}
}
public void render(){
drawRect(0, 0, width, height, 0x000000);
drawRect(10, 10, width - 20, height - 20, 0x0000ff);
}
public void update(){
int delta = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime);
if(delta >= 1000 / 30){
render();
lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
}

//in a different class, contains main()

public class Main{
public static Panel pan;
public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container c = frame.getContentPane();
c.setPreferredSize(500, 500);
pan = new Panel(500, 500);
frame.add(pan);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
new runThread().run();
}
class runThread extends Thread{
public void run(){
while(true){
pan.update();
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: If this were my problem and I were seeking help here, I'd take a little time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since I'd know that this would be the best and quickest way to get folks to fully understand my problem and then help me. Please consider this; you won't regret it, trust me!

Comment: One way to get images for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: `Graphics#drawImage` should use `this` as the `ImageObserver`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that didn't help.

Comment: Well, until you can provide  a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, the only thing you will get a wild guesses (but you should supply `this` as the `ImageObserver` when drawing images to components as a general rule)

Comment: I tried asking him for that @MadProgrammer with no success. Perhaps your request will yield more fruit.

Comment: See [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: @trashgod You mean to call `update()`? Would that make a difference?

Comment: Your program incorrectly synchronized in several ways; the result is indeterminate; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Care to elaborate?

Comment: The [example cited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) does not flicker.

Comment: @trashgod I have a 15-class program, at the moment, that uses something I've already made to render it. I can't see what difference between my program and the example you give causes the flicker. Is it the use(or lack of) `invokeLater()`?

Answer (score 2):

Because your program is incorrectly synchronized in several ways, the result is indeterminate. Swing GUI objects must be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); this is *required* on all supported platforms. As discussed in [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) runs at 50 Hz without flicker.

> I have a 15-class program…

In larger programs, you can search for EDT violations using one of the approaches cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513). Also review the animation techniques suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835051/230513).