# Blitting in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I do not know java (usually write in c)

How can I do efficiently some way of blitting 
pixel array content onto a window in java?

I need (in loop) `blit pixels[][]` onto a window

I could use something like

```
 pixels[][] -> MemoryImageSource -> Image -> drawImage
```

but creating and deleting  `MemoryImageSource` and `Image` 
in every frame seems strange to me - how it can be
done simply and reasonably efficiently? Could someone
give a code example, tnx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally in Java it's easier to work with the native `Image` types and use their derived graphics. [Behind the scenes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/e947a98ea3c1/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/pipe/DrawImage.java) Java uses blits as well, so the higher level abstractions is made to easen the workload.

But if there's no way to abstract on the pixel data you can use [Raster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) and [WritableRaster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html) (where you can replace portions of the array) as an alternative to your solution. These rasters can be used with a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) which then can be drawn using the drawImage method you mentioned. I found one way of doing it [here](http://www.cap-lore.com/code/java/JavaPixels.html) which basically creates the Image and then retrieves the raster for future manipulation.

```
int x, y = 100;
BufferedImage image   = new BufferedImage(x, y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
```

That raster (or just small areas of it) can then be manipulated and repainted.

This might improve performance slightly since the distance from you pixel-array to the screen is shorter. But I think very few people fully understands the entire depths of the AWT api - and it all depends on the native implementations of course - so my idea contains a healthy part of speculation ;-) 
But I hope it helped..

Comment: Will check it. And as to creating and deleting Images in every frame (this is in my example), can it be done such way, or should never not? (found some better example in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html with newPixels method - but as far as i tried to run it it doea not work (no update to image), Anyway tnx much for answer, was a good one

Comment: Well it always costs to instantiate objects and when dealing with graphics performance is almost always an issue. I'd go with as few calculations in paint-methods as possible. Especially if you're copying each array at every tick - that can be expensive :-) Glad to help

Answer (score 5):

For speed, you can pre-compute variations of the `ColorModel`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7546025/230513).

[image]