# Java: SineGrating in JPanel with Java2D

Tags: java, swing, opengl, user-interface, java-2d

I was wondering if it is possible to create a sine-grating like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sinegrating&safe=off&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=mu-6U4T_KYumyATDk4CIAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw&biw=1918&bih=886) in a JPanel using only Java2D.

I am not very adept with Swing and Java2D jet, so there might be simple things I am missing. If it is in fact not possible to do this could someone please provide me with an easy tutorial how to use OpenGL with JOGL inside a JPanel? 
I know Java2D and JOGL work together quite nicely but I really dont know how to initialize things to get a OpenGL graphic to show up in my normal GUI.

Comment: You might experiment with `java.awt.LinearGradientPaint` or this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7544559/230513).

Comment: trashgod's suggestion should be enough if you want to stick with Java2D. If you're afraid of learning how to use JOGL/OpenGL, you can look at Jzy3D even for 2D stuffs, it uses JOGL under the hood but it's easier to use. What do you mean by "normal GUI"?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies!
java.awt.LinearGradientPaint was in fact exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The question was essentially answered by trashgod. Using LinearGradientPaint one can create a real sine-wave grating by using a linear grading with many samplePoints.
An example function that creates a sine-wave grating is below.

Thanks again for your help!

```
public LinearGradientPaint getSineWaveGrating(int numberCycles, int samplePoints, Point2D startP, Point2D endP, Color color) {   
  float[] fractions = new float[samplePoints+1];
  Color[] colors    = new Color[samplePoints+1];

  for(int i=0;i<=samplePoints;i++) {
    fractions[i]        = i*(1/(float)samplePoints); 
    double cosArg       = Math.PI+((i*numberCycles*2*Math.PI)/samplePoints);
    double rectifiedCos = (Math.cos(cosArg)+1)/2;
    colors[i]           = new Color(color.getRed(),color.getGreen(),color.getBlue(),(int)(255*rectifiedCos));
  }

  return new LinearGradientPaint(startP, endP, fractions, colors);
}
```